# why my ClientScene.RegisterSpawnHandler doesn't work?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, spawn, unity-networking

I'm trying to spawn a child object (has network Identity) of a parent (doesn't have network identity). So I'm passing the child of the prefab and it works. Spawning works just fine but it doesn't go through my spawnhandler, neither on server nor on clients ("custom spawner" is never printed in other words). So spawned objects are only the childs, and the parent isn't with them consequently. In handler, I'm trying to make a parent for the spawned object. Here's the relevant codes:

```
 public class CustomNetworkManager : NetworkManager{

 public GameObject prefab;
 private void Awake()
 {
     ....
     ClientScene.RegisterPrefab(prefab.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
     var prefabAssetId = prefab.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity().assetId;
     ClientScene.RegisterSpawnHandler(prefabAssetId , SpawnWithParent, UnSpawnWithParent);
 }

 public static void Spawn(GameObject prefab)
 {
     NetworkServer.Spawn(prefab);
 }

 public GameObject SpawnWithParent(Vector3 position, NetworkHash128 assetId)
 {
     print("custom spawner");
     var parent = Instantiate(new GameObject("parent"), position, Quaternion.identity);
     var chlid= Instantiate(prefab.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
     chlid.transform.position = parent.transform.position;
     chlid.transform.parent = parent.transform;

     return prefab.gameObject;
 }

 public void UnSpawnWithParent(GameObject spawned)
 {
     print("custom unspawner");
     spawned.SetActive(false);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

So I told myself let's give it a try by removing the line about registering the prefab before it all, and It actually fixed the problem! So it seems if you're going to use the spawnhandler system, you should not register that particular prefab at all! because for some reason it messes the system up.

So I deleted this line and it fixed the problem:

```
**//ClientScene.RegisterPrefab(prefab.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);**
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly have a look on [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.ClientScene.RegisterSpawnHandler.html) link. As it says:

> This should be used when no prefab exists for the spawned objects - such as when they are constructed dynamically at runtime from configuration data.

Maybe it could be a good idea to check if you need this functionality or if the RegisterPrefab is enough.
Hope it helps to clear the situation.
[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.ClientScene.RegisterPrefab.html) is the link for RegisterPrefab.